# React-native Troubles while running project on android

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I created a project with

> npx react-native init

While development I used only iOS and xcode and today for a first time I run it on android... And got an error in time of build process. The error is

> error: cannot find symbol ReactNativeConfig.DEFAULT_CONFIG,

In MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java I have an import

> import com.facebook.react.fabric.ReactNativeConfig;

and next code

```
return new FabricJSIModuleProvider(
                reactApplicationContext,
                componentFactory,
                ReactNativeConfig.DEFAULT_CONFIG,
                viewManagerRegistry);
```

in Gradle.properties file JSI is disabled

```
newArchEnabled=false
```

I googled nothing about this error, so maybe someone here knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to rn 0.69 fixed the problem.